# Invite facebook friends in my website using facebook API

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a website in C#, using the Facebook API and getting logged in user's friend list. I bind this list in a Datalist with checkbox, friends picture, Name and UserID.

When I check some checkboxes and click on a button, I want to send some sort of invite to the checked friends. I want to send the invite via a private message, notification or any other solution (but *not* on the user's wall). Is this possible?

I have checked all posts ,which are already in Stackoverflow. 
And also checked this one http://www.fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:server-fbml-multi-friend-selector

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called `"App-generated Requests"`.  These are requests that are sent from inside your application without needing your users to see or act on the [requests dialog.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

The following code is taken from the Facebook documentation - 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

```
<?php 

  $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo("App Request sent?", $result);
?>
```

> Once sent, new requests a user has received are visible as a counter
>   on your application's bookmark and it also increments the counter next
>   to the appropriate Dashboard.

The code is in PHP but it is using the very generic `file_get_contents()` method.  You can use this logic with any language capable of making HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Lix, But it is used for Canvas and Mobile App ,not for Website. Any way can you tell me ,how can we post on user's friends wall and which permission required for it?
Thanks Again!! :)

Comment: You can setup an application with a canvas that simply redirects back to your website.  You have to have a canvas URL in order to use requests...  With regard to posting on peoples walls, you'll nee the `publish_stream` permission...

Answer (score 0):

This code will post on your friend's wall  ,whatever you want to post:

```
              for (Int32 i = 1; i < DLFbFriend.Items.Count; i++){

                CheckBox Chkbox =(CheckBox)DLFbFriend.Items[i].FindControl("chkUserID");
                if (Chkbox.Checked)
                {
                    HiddenField hdfUserId = (HiddenField)DLFbFriend.Items[i].FindControl("hdfUserID");
                    string d = hdfUserId.Value;//friend's facebook generated id,whom you want to invite
                    String link = "what ever you want to post";
                    string url1 = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + d + "/feed?access_token=" + Request.QueryString["access_token"] + "&link=" + link + "&from=" + Session["Pinny_USER"].ToString().Split('~')[0] + "&name=Register with Pinny&message=Your friend invites you&picture=http://168.144.124.15/images/logoPinny.jpeg";
                    HttpWebRequest request1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url1);
                    request1.Method = "POST";
                    // execute the request
                    HttpWebResponse response1 = (HttpWebResponse)request1.GetResponse();

                    // we will read data via the response stream
                    System.IO.Stream ReceiveStream1 = response1.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader readStream1 = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream1);
                    string json1 = readStream1.ReadToEnd();
                    countinvited += 1;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Now facebook not providing direct posting on anybody wall. Now you need to post anything on your wall and then you can post that on your friend's wall.